# The interpretation of the word “pry”

Tags: american-english, british-english

Can the word "pry" be interpreted negatively (offensively)? For example, “to pry into other people's affairs” or is it still possible to interpret the meaning just as “curious”? I am interested in the attitude to this word English native speakers. I am not English native speakers.

Or for example: "be pry" equals "be curious"?

I relied on these sources. The question was inspired by the observation that no one uses the word "pry" for commercial purposes (marketing), for example slogans, headings, etc.

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=ru&text=pry), [Yandex Translate](https://translate.yandex.ru/?lang=en-ru&text=pry), [Multitran](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?s=pry&l1=1&l2=2), [Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/pry#%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: What did you find when you looked up *pry* in some [dictionaries](https://www.onelook.com/?w=pry&ls=a)?

Comment: Ambiguous information in different dictionaries.

Comment: Dmitry, I asked that question as a prompt for you to [edit] your post to **include the research you've done** - i.e. tell us what the "ambiguous information" was and where you found it. Failing to include this information not only encourages downvotes, it also risks your post being closed/deleted for lack of research. Please see [ask] for further guidance. :-)

Comment: Topic was updated. So, I want say thanks people that indicated on links of good dictionaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Pry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pry#Etymology_1)* in the sense of "ask for information" is almost always negative in connotation.

*[Pry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pry#Verb_2)* in the sense of "use a stick or bar to open something" is neutral in connotation, and is a shortening of *prise/prize*.

(This usage of *pry* is a verb, so one can't say "be pry" in the way one can say "be curious".)

Comment: That is "pry" can't be a noun? But in your example (link wiki), "prey" can also be a noun.

Comment: Well, if *pry* can mean "An excessively inquisitive person", then I guess someone could "be a pry".  But I have never heard that usage.

Comment: @DmitryS. The main noun sense of "pry" is "a lever used to prise something open", for example a crowbar or stick.

Answer (score 1):

**to pry**  [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/pry_1)

> [intransitive] to be interested in someone’s personal life in a way
>   that is **annoying or offensive**

As in:

> - I just glanced at the letter; I didn’t mean to pry.
> - The press continues to pry into their affairs.

Depending on the context, **to pry** is meaning to be *intrusive* and or *offensive*, though the phrase **prying eyes** is a more neutral 'curious', but still annoyingly so.

The [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/153665?rskey=7oc51k&result=5#eid) gives this definition:

> ... to peer **intrusively**; ... to seek out secret or private
>   information, ... **to spy**.

[Etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=pry) cites early usage as being more inquisitive than obtrusively inquisitive.  My sense of current usage is more to the negative or offensive.

> "look inquisitively," c. 1300, from prien "to peer in," of unknown
>   origin, perhaps related to late Old English bepriwan "to wink."
>   Related: Pried; prying. As a noun, "act of prying," from 1750; meaning
>   "inquisitive person" is from 1845.